# send window.location a variable,which fetch from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to send a variable in `window.location` which variable stores the database data.

**Code**

```
window.location=data.page_name;
```

in above code `data.page_name` fetch a page_name from database via `ajax`.but it not working.
Please help...

Comment: You need to redirect the user up to the `data.page_name` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect then try this :

```
window.location.href = data.page_name;
```